# How to change Status Bar in tmux window

Tags: tmux

I feel very bad when seeing Status Bar in bottom during using tmux.
How to change it to top position in tmux window?

My related OS is below---
**c5259479@bsa0483:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 9.10 \n \l**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can add set-option -g status-position top to ~/.tmux.conf